# Beta integrals substitutions

Tags: integration, beta-function

I am trying to evaluate the following two beta function integrals

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k B(k,5/2) = \int ^1_0 \left[\frac{(1-t)^{3/2}}{t}\right]\frac{1}{1-xt}dt
$$

and

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k B(k+1,3/2) = \int ^1_0 t\sqrt{1-t}\frac{1}{1-xt}dt
$$

How can I proceed?

My attempt at the second integral. With $u = \sqrt{1-t}$

$$
\int ^1_0 t\sqrt{1-t}\frac{1}{1-xt}dt= -2\int^1_0\frac{u^2(1-u^2)}{1-x(1-u^2)}du
$$

My attempt at the first integral with again $u=\sqrt{1-t}$ is

$$
\int ^1_0 \left[\frac{(1-t)^{3/2}}{t}\right]\frac{1}{1-xt}dt = -2\int^1_0\left[\frac{u^4}{1-u^2}\right]\frac{1}{1-x(1-u^2)}du
$$

Comment: How do you know the two things (sum and integral) are equal?

Comment: @Daniel I think he used the integral representation of beta function, changed the order of the two operators and then used geometric series.

Comment: What did you try buddy?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari I am confident that they should converge, the summations are generating functions for probability distributions, so I can always normalise them with a multiplicative constant. I have tried a few substitutions, $z=t\sqrt{1-t}$ and $z=\sqrt{1-t}$ for the second one, but I couldn't make progress. For the top I have tried $z=(1-t)^{3/2}/t$ and $z=(1-t)^{3/2}$. Perhaps one of those would work, it might just be my rather rubbish integration skills! Thank you.

Comment: @DanielC As Laxmi has already said, I changed the order of the integral and used a geometric series. Cheers

Comment: @Angus try $t=\sin^2 u$. I think that would work.